# How to let hibernate don't override the specified UUID?

Tags: hibernate, uuid

I defined a entity with a uuid primary key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SITES")
public class Site extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 32)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
}
```

It works fine, but I found hibernate will always override the specified id:

When I save a `Site` object with specified uuid `402881e533fe2de70133fe2df6790000`, like:

```
Site site = new Site();
site.setId("402881e533fe2de70133fe2df6790000");
siteDao.save(site);
```

Print the id:

```
System.out.println(site.id);
```

Get:

```
402881e534110dc30134110dd4e80000
```

Is there any way to ask hibernate don't override my specified uuid?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741048/7430325) answer by [alediaferia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956531/alediaferia) is correct, but unfortunately it's not available now because that site is down.
But you can find [copy of original article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112041403/https://rajivrnair.dev/custom-hibernate-uuid/) on Web Archive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why you want to use setId(). You should let Hibernate handle the ids and everything is right.

Hibernate sets the id if you persist a new Object.

Comment: I don't think this is an acceptable response. The OP made the point clear. Why replying with a different question?

Comment: You are right. The Answer to the specific question is: Don't use a @GeneratedValue and Hibernate won't override your default ID.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post: http://rajivrnair.github.io/custom-hibernate-uuid/

Concretely, you can create a custom UUID generator that skips the generation if a UUID has already been set for the targeted field. This is useful, especially when testing your code.